# JndiException when using Hibernate 4.0 with Tomcat 7 and JSF 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

After the application deploye, when method is execute , i am getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/JSF_HIBER/ORACLE]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at com.utils.HibernateUtils.<clinit>(HibernateUtils.java:19)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed through a java: URL
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.parseName(SelectorContext.java:776)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:135)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
    ... 47 more
```

**Context.xml**

```
<Resource name="JSF_HIBER/ORACLE" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
    username="****" password="**** driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@99.99.999.999:1521:xe" />
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/JSF_HIBER/ORACLE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping class="com.entity.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>JSF_HIBER</description>
        <res-ref-name>JSF_HIBER/ORACLE</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

i don't know why i am getting this error, please help me...

Comment: Which `context.xml` are you talking about?  The global one or one in `META-INF`?

Answer (score 7):

You must add a slash between "java:" and "comp" in the hibernate.cfg.xml file :

`<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/JSF_HIBER/ORACLE</property>`

It will probably solve the issue

Comment: Nicely done!  You are a gentleman and a scholar.  This fixed the problem for me.  Strangely the old string works when you don't use Hibernate to obtain a `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Comment: @Jimit Tank why this answer is not accepted? Does it solve your problem, it solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need the following in the `META-INF/context.xml` to link your global JNDI resources to the application specific ones:

```
<Context>
  <ResourceLink name="JSF_HIBER/ORACLE"
            global="JSF_HIBER/ORACLE"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
</Context>
```

which links your global datasource `JSF_HIBER/ORACLE` to your local one `java:comp/env/JSF_HIBER/ORACLE`.

EDIT:

If you don't want to create an application level link, you can use the global url instead:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">JSF_HIBER/ORACLE</property>
```

Comment: I think problem is in my hibernet code.. pleses check it's corect or not..

try {

   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   conf.configure();
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
     .applySettings(conf.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
   SESSION_FACTORY = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
  } catch (Throwable ex) {
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
  }

Comment: I did say add the code in your `META-INF/context.xml` not `server.xml`.  The error message points to a JNDI lookup that's not quite setup correctly.

Comment: what i understand create new application level context.xml in META-INF/
is it ?

Comment: When i use globel url...
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">JSF_HIBER/ORACLE</property>
then i am getting below exception :: 

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name JSF_HIBER is not bound in this Context
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:145)
 at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:135)

Comment: i also try other way.. to create a new tomcate.xml in META-INF/
but it does't work..